# EJB3.0 @EJB annotation in Managed Bean JSF2 Websphere 7 impossible?

Tags: jsf-2, ejb-3.0, websphere-7

The websphere 7 only supports Java EE 5, but JSF2 is contained in Java EE 6, is there any tricks to implement @EJB annotation in ManagedBean?

Answer (score 1):

The `@EJB` annotation is part of EJB 3.0 which is part of Java EE 5. It is not part of JSF 2.0 nor Java EE 6. It should work just fine on JSF 1.x managed beans in a Java EE 5 environment. The only difference with JSF 2.x managed beans in Java EE 6 is that you can't annotate JSF managed beans with `@ManagedBean`, but have to register them in `faces-config.xml`. That shouldn't make difference for the `@EJB` annotation.

Answer (score 0):

JSF2 can be in Java EE 5 as well. The reason why annotations do not work is about Websphere. See the following link for details: http://www.java.net/node/701374#comment-813807

This issue seems to be fixed in Websphere 7.0.0.19 :
http://wasbehindtheglass.blogspot.co.uk/